# Dynamic variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, slider, dynamic-variables

I have a situation where i need to create dynamic variable in test1 ,test2 form. I know it should be done using array or object index but somehow i am not able to rsolve things. I have a silder and using it in multiple places.

Js for silder:

```
 //code for slider 1
    var sliders1 = [];
    jQuery('.slider_1').each(function() {   
    sliders1.push(new Slider(this))
  })

 //code for slider 2
var sliders2 = [];
jQuery('.slider_2').each(function() {
sliders2.push(new Slider(this))
})


    var Slider = function() { this.initialize.apply(this, arguments) }
    Slider.prototype = {
    initialize: function(slider) {
    this.ul = slider.children[0]
    this.li = this.ul.children

    // make <ul> as large as all <li>’s
    this.ul.style.width = (this.li[0].clientWidth * this.li.length) + 'px'

    this.currentIndex = 0
    },

    goTo: function(index) {
    // filter invalid indices
    if (index < 0 || index > this.li.length - 1)
    return

    // move <ul> left
    this.ul.style.left = '-' + (100 * index) + '%'

    this.currentIndex = index
    },

    goToPrev: function() {
    this.goTo(this.currentIndex - 1)
    },

    goToNext: function() {
    this.goTo(this.currentIndex + 1)
    }
    }
```

Now situation is i need to make it dynamic. this is what i have tried till now.
 can i make silders1 , sliders2 somehow.so that i can run it according to the things mentioned above

```
 //slider count
 var count= jQuery("div[id*='sliders']").length;

 var silders = {};
for( var i=1; i <= count;i++){

    sliders[i] = [];
    var class1 = '.silder_'+i;
    jQuery(class1).each(function() {    
    sliders[i].push(new Slider(this))
});
}
```

And in my HTml it is called as

```
//suppose for first silder

<a href="javascript:sliders1[0].goToNext()">  for go next buttton
```

Kindly help me with some solution . I am bit confused Here.

Thanks!!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35221108/how-to-get-random-variables-value-in-javascript/35250618#35250618

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize sliders:

```
var sliders = {};
```

Otherwise, the line

```
sliders[i] = [];
```

will cause an exception since sliders is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to iterate through numbers starting at `1`, until it finds no element with that class.
Also,  don't forget to declare the `sliders` array first.

Something like this:

```
var n = 1;
var sliders = [];

while($('.slider_'+n).length > 0)
{
    sliders[n] = [];
    $('.slider_'+n).each(function() {
        sliders[n].push(new Slider(this));
    });
    n++;
}
```

Comment: Check how i am calling it using html. I am getting exception there. goToPrev not found. it i call it like javascript:sliders[1][0].goToNext()

Comment: @Creator You never initialize the 0th element. Your for loop goes from 1 to count `for( var i=1; i <= count;i++)`

Answer (score 0):

Multiple Silder on a single Page: Works with SlickSlider and Owlsider

```js
/* Setting the variable `carouselCount` to 0. */
var carouselCount = 0;

/* Looping through each carousel on the page. */
$(".owl-carousel").each(function () {
  /* Setting the id of the carousel to owl-carousel-0, owl-carousel-1, etc. */
  $(this).attr("id", "owl-carousel-" + carouselCount);
  /* It's setting the variable `carouselID` to the current carousel. */
  var carouselID = $("#owl-carousel-" + carouselCount);

  carouselID.owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    loop: true,
    dots: true,
    lazyLoad: true,
    dotsEach: true,
    pagination: true,
    rewindSpeed: 0,
    nav: true,
    navText: ["", ""],
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 8000,
    autoHeight: false,
  });

  $(".owl-prev").html(
    '<span><img src="/img/icons/arrow.svg" style="-webkit-transform:rotate(180deg); -ie-transform:rotate(180deg); transform:rotate(180deg);" alt="arrow right" /></span>'
  );
  $(".owl-next").html(
    '<span><img src="/img/icons/arrow.svg" alt="arrow right" /></span>'
  );

  $(".owl-item").height();
  $(".owl-pagination").css(
    "left",
    $(window).width() / 2 - $(".owl-pagination").width() / 2
  );

  /* It's incrementing the variable `carouselCount` by 1. */
  carouselCount++;
});

$(window).resize(function () {
  $(".owl-item").height($(window).height());
  $(".owl-pagination").css(
    "left",
    $(window).width() / 2 - $(".owl-pagination").width() / 2
  );
});
```

```css
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```